# how to use left join to output results from a column that are null using two different data types?

Tags: mysql, database

hi im having trouble doing a left join that outputs all customers who haven't made an order yet. im getting a conversion error and have tried using cast to convert it but it doesnt work. any help would be appreciated

**here are my tables and data:**`

create table Customers(
   Cust_code varchar(2) primary key ,
   [first_name] varchar(30) not null,
   last_name varchar(30) not null,
   address varchar(100) not null,
   city varchar(35) not null)

```
create table Cust_Order(
order_no int ,
Cust_code varchar(2) not null,
order_date date not null, 
meth_pmt varchar(30) not null,
constraint Ord_order_no_pk primary key(order_no),
constraint Cus_cust_code_fk foreign key(Cust_code) references Customers)


create table Product(
product_id int ,
product_name varchar(100) not null,
product_price decimal(8, 2) not null,
constraint Pro_product_id_pk primary key(product_id))


create table Order_Line(
order_no int ,
product_id int ,
qty int not null,
sale_price decimal(8,2) not null,
constraint Ord_order_no_product_id_pk primary key(order_no, product_id),
constraint Pro_product_id_fk foreign key(product_id) references Product)

insert into Customers (Cust_code, [first_name], last_name, address, city)
values('A1', 'Kath', 'Morgan','122 Lilain Street', 'Palmerston North'),
  ('A2','Mike','Smith','67 Golf Hill Drive','Wellington'),
  ('A3','Glen','Hoddle','San Quentin Ave','Palmerston North'),
  ('A4','Dan','Boone','Alamo Road','Wellington')


insert into Cust_Order (order_no, Cust_code, order_date, meth_payment)
values(1, 'A1','2014-01-16','CC'),
    (2, 'A1','2014-02-16','CC'),
    (3, 'A2','2014-01-16','CHEQUE'),
    (4, 'A3','2014-03-17','CC')


insert into Product (product_id, product_name, product_price)
values(1, 'Network Card', 58.00),
    (2, 'Motherboard', 150.00),
    (3, 'Video Card', 232.00)


insert into Order_Line (order_no, product_id, qty, sale_price)
values(1,1,3,70.00),
    (1,2,1,170.00),
    (1,3,2,300.00),
    (2,1,2,70.00),
    (2,3,1,300.00),
    (3,1,2,70.00),
    (4,1,3,70.00)
```

**my select statement using left join which should output the one customer who hasn't made an order**

```
select first_name + last_name as 'Customers who have not made an order', 
order_no from Customers as c
left join Cust_Order as o
on c.Cust_code = o.order_no 
where order_no is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join condition needs to match on the customer codes.  Other than this, the logic of your query is correct, but MySQL doesn't use `+` for string concatenation, this is SQL Server syntax.  Use the `CONCAT` function instead:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS `Customers who have not made an order`
FROM Customers AS c
LEFT JOIN Cust_Order AS o
    ON c.Cust_code = o.Cust_code 
WHERE o.Cust_code IS NULL;
```

The ANSI concatenation operator is `||`, and you may also use it in MySQL if you set the appropriate mode:

```
SET sql_mode = PIPES_AS_CONCAT
```

Comment: still having issues with not being able to convert the varchar value as an int. Cust_code being a varchar while order_no is an int, so my query fails

Comment: I can't relate because my query won't generate this error.

Comment: this is the error message. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A1' to data type int.

Comment: I can't comment, because you are not running my query, you're doing something else.  If you can concisely tell me what you're doing, maybe I can help.

Comment: i want to output two columns one for the customers fullname and the other order_no. it should result in one specific output being                Dan boone, null

Comment: you were right actually i was trying to make c.cust_code = o.order_no instead of c.cust_code = o.Cust_code. only just started using joins so not very good at them

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a LEFT JOIN, try:

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT(C.first_name, ' ', C.last_name) AS 'Customers who have not made an order'
FROM Customers C LEFT JOIN Cust_Order CO 
ON C.Cust_code=CO.Cust_code
GROUP BY Customer_FullName
HAVING COUNT(B.*)=0;
```

Or you can make use of EXISTS.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(C.first_name, ' ', C.last_name) AS 'Customers who have not made an order'    
FROM Customers C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Cust_Order CO WHERE C.Cust_code=CO.Cust_code);
```

See [MySQL join made easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join) for insights on using joins.